# ElasticSearchHighLevelClient springboot Autoconfiguration not working

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to autoconfigure elasticsearch high-level rest client using this documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-elasticsearch

I added the following properties to my application.properties:

```
spring.elasticsearch.rest.uris=https://hostname.com 
spring.elasticsearch.rest.read-timeout=10s
spring.elasticsearch.rest.username= user
spring.elasticsearch.rest.password= password
```

I added these dependencies in my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

and a property

```
<elasticsearch.version>7.2.1</elasticsearch.version>
```

In my application I did this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

But when I try to use the HighLevelClient it gives me NullPointerException

```
 @Autowired
 private RestHighLevelClient client;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: To me, `elasticsearch-rest-client` dependency looks unnecessary as you are already have `elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client`, can u remove this and try again ??

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Amit Still not working. Do I have to write a configuration class as well? Or Whatever I have done is enough?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the stacktrace for the `NullPointerException`.

You did not write which versions you use (Spring Boot, Spring Data Elasticsearch). But the current Spring Boot 2.2.2 targets Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x  which uses Elasticsearch 6.8.5. So this won't work with an Elasticsearch 7 cluster. Support for Elasticsearch 7 is coming with the next version (Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.0)

Comment: I am not using Spring Data Elasticsearch and following this
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using spring-boot-autoconfigure dependency because RestHighLevelClient bean is initialized by this library based on the presence of RestHighLevelClient in the classpath. Check the dependency tree for the presence of spring-boot-autoconfigure.

Comment: I do have spring-boot-autoconfigure in my dependencies.

Comment: Provide the stacktrace of the error. Also, try debugging the class "RestClientConfigurations" in spring-boot-autoconfigure.